# I created protobuf model file in TensorFlow and used it in python with opencv package. Why is this not working?

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, machine-learning, protocol-buffers

I tried to use .pb and .pbtxt files with the python OpenCV package. But it didn't work. Here is my code,

```
import cv2

# Load a model imported from Tensorflow
tensorflowNet = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow('saved_model.pb', 'label_map.pbtxt')

# Input image
img = cv2.imread('image (60).png')
rows, cols, channels = img.shape

# Use the given image as input, which needs to be blob(s).
tensorflowNet.setInput(cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, size=(640, 640), swapRB=True, crop=False))

# Runs a forward pass to compute the net output
networkOutput = tensorflowNet.forward()

# Loop on the outputs
for detection in networkOutput[0, 0]:

    score = float(detection[2])
    if score > 0.2:
        left = detection[3] * cols
        top = detection[4] * rows
        right = detection[5] * cols
        bottom = detection[6] * rows

        # draw a red rectangle around detected objects
        cv2.rectangle(img, (int(left), int(top)), (int(right), int(bottom)), (0, 0, 255), thickness=2)

# Show the image with a rectagle surrounding the detected objects
cv2.imshow('Image', img)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here is the error,

```
[libprotobuf ERROR D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\3rdparty\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\wire_format_lite.cc:581] String field 'opencv_tensorflow.FunctionDef.Node.ret' contains invalid UTF-8 data when parsing a protocol buffer. Use the 'bytes' type if you intend to send raw bytes. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Disk_4\Python Projects\FDAM\main.py", line 14, in <module>
    tensorflowNet = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow('saved_model.pb', 'label_map.pbtxt')
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\tensorflow\tf_io.cpp:42: error: (-2:Unspecified error) FAILED: ReadProtoFromBinaryFile(param_file, param). Failed to parse GraphDef file: saved_model.pb in function 'cv::dnn::ReadTFNetParamsFromBinaryFileOrDie'
```

I found this code in https://jeanvitor.com/tensorflow-object-detecion-opencv/ and changed it with my file names.
I trained the model and generated this saved_model.pb file in TensorFlow.
Why is this code not working? please help me. This is my first project with machine learning.

Comment: there is no real support for saved_model yet. the code you found, is using a tf 1.x graphdef based model

Comment: Is that correct filename? 'image (60).png'

Comment: Yes. every file names are correct. I double-checked each one of them